# I'm using Azure Streaming analytics but it keeps failing but I don't dee why

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I've set up a simple insert query for the Streaming Analytics service to dump data from the event hub into a Azure SQL DB. Problem is that it fails, when I look at the diagnostics page all it says is it encountered a runtime error:

Operation name

Process Events: Processing events Runtime Error

Time stamp

Fri Sep 30 2016 15:46:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

How can I determine what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check Activity Log in Azure Portal? It may have more details. If not, please send your subscription id and job name to askasa@microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the activity log (I'm new to Azure). The log did not give any additional information on the error but a couple of hours later there's an entry stating that there was a connectivity problem for the west US SQL instance and that MS engineers are resolving the problem. So I assume that was the issue.